# Is it possible to stop a mobile device from multi-access?

Tags: security, mobile

I have a site that sells an audio download.  I am setting up the system for mobile devices,  but am running into problems figuring out how to keep someone from giving their password to someone else, and that other person streaming the audio for free.

It appears I can't distinguish a user by the MAC address on their device, and setting a cookie would probably become a hassle if the user had cookies disabled or deleted them at a later date.

At this point I'm considering the cookie method,  and if a user 'loses' their cookie, they can request a new login - which will simply send an email to the original customers address with a self-generating unique link that will supply them with the new cookie.   Kind of a hassle for the end user though, and all they'd really have to do is just forward the link to whoever they wanted to give the account information to.

Example:

1. Joe buys an audio program from the site using his iPod.
2. Joe's friend Bill says he'd like to hear it too.
3. Joe gives Bill his username/password to the site.
4. Bill logs on using Joes' username/password and gets the audio download for free.

Number 1 and 2 are good :)
Number 3 is the start of the potential problem.
Number 4 is what I want to stop.

Any ideas on how to do this? Or am I just out of luck on this one?